# Why did Thanos give the mind-controller Scepter to Loki?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *The Avengers: Age of Ultron*, we learned that Loki's scepter is powered by

> an Infinity Stone (Mind Stone).

Thanos is in pursuit of all six Infinity Stones to conquer the universe. In the mid-credit scene of *The Avengers: Age of Ultron*, we saw

> Thanos wearing his Infinity Gauntlet glove which had empty slots for Infinity Stones.

Why did Thanos give such a precious thing to Loki? While it could turn out to be useful, it wasn't a 100% necessary thing. And, we now know that

> he lost the only Infinity Stone he had.

Comment: You gotta speculate to accumulate.

Comment: I speculated on another question like this that Thanos is treating the stones like an experiment.  There's no better way to get information on mysterious uber-powers than hand them out and let someone else screw up first.

Comment: Your last spoiler is unproven. There are 2 we don't know about, and he may have one or both of the others.

Comment: @Lego It's possible, but in the mid-credit scene Infinity Gauntlet of Thanos was displayed. It had zero Infinity Stones.

Comment: And a smart gun owner doesn't store a gun with bullets in.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr But what if you have a smart-gun?

Comment: @Xantec Given how smart devices in the Marvel universe have a history of not doing what their creators intended, a smart-gun owner wouldn't let it *near* bullets before the owner was ready.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Without knowing very much about the Marvel Cinematic Universe's Mind Infinity Stone, it is presumptuous for us, as viewers, to think Thanos didn't have a plan when he gave the staff to Loki or that its loss by Loki wasn't part of said plan.

- Thanos should be considered the consummate **[Magnificent Bastard](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MagnificentBastard)**. His plans have wheels within wheels and the "loss" of something may have nothing to do with what has actually occurred. Thanos IS utterly devious, he has played everyone in this orchestra to perfection, he is clearly motivated to gather the Infinity Stones and has not put himself at risk. Not even once.

[image]

**A sign of Thanos' genius:**

- He has managed to learn about the Avengers, discover the depths of their technological capacity and potentially infiltrate SHIELD all by using Loki to confront the Avengers. We have no proof that the Mind stone isn't capable of reading the minds of whomever are near it. Since it is sitting in the middle of SHIELD in a lab somewhere, how do we know Thanos isn't listening? We don't.

[image]

- He has learned the capacity and potential danger of the Power stone and rid himself of a potential threat, Ronan the Accuser. He know also knows where the Power Stone is and can likely retrieve it whenever he likes. He still has a former member of his personal guard INSIDE the Guardians of the Galaxy, keeping an eye on the unknown threat that is Peter Quill.

[image]

- Thanos surely knows where the Aether is and now that the Collector has been frightened by the power of the Stone, he may also be more amendable to getting rid of it in the future. And that assumes the Collector isn't on the payroll of the Mad Titan already.

[image]

- Thanos also knows the Tesseract is in the hands of the Asgardians. Who is currently at the head of Asgard? His flunky, Loki.

[image]

- Thanos has not had to personally involve himself in any of the actions taking place and still has not revealed any of his capacity, technology or technological assets. Nebula got away and Gamora is still, potentially, undercover.

[image]

**It would be a gross underestimation of Thanos if we assume he hadn't had a plan in place, from the moment Loki "lost" the Mind Stone to SHIELD. If I were a betting man, I'd bet Thanos is watching the stones being revealed and once they are, he will note their locations and then simply gather them at his convenience.**

Comment: You are right on that, my confusion but you need to change that image because mind stone is yellow and tesseract is blue.

Comment: Your first image should be updated wrt the Time Gem given Dr. Strange.

Comment: This is a great answer, but this part stood out to me: `"We have no proof that the Mind stone isn't capable of reading the minds of whomever are near it."` This isn't really how proof works. We also don't have proof that the mind stone isn't capable of creating magical unicorns. :)

Comment: Which movie does the second picture from the bottom belong to?

Answer (score -11):

Ultron obviously had the Soul Gem, which is now on Vision's head from what we learned from Avengers 2.

Heimdall has the last gem which is the Time Gem. It is what I believe keeps Odin alive, and what I presume allowed them to rebuild the bifrost. You can see it on Heimdall's new armour in Thor 2.

[image: HeimdallArmourTimeGem]

I also believe that there is unrest/war against Asgard because it is known, not by the Asgardians but by those that oppose, that the second gauntlet is owned by Odin (or the one complete gauntlet which you can see in Thor 1).

[image: RightHandInfinityGauntlet]

In Avengers 2 Thanos is seen lifting the Left handed gauntlet.

Comment: How does this answer why Thanos gave the scepter to Loki?

Comment: Thanos gave it to Loki to cause more unrest/war toward Asgard because he knows they have the other gauntlet.

Comment: Then you should add that to your answer

Comment: I thought it seemed implied.

Comment: Actually, they used the Tesseract to rebuild the Bifrost: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/49461/3567

Comment: “Ultron obviously had the Soul Gem” In *Age of Ultron*, Thor says that this is the Mind Stone, not the Soul Stone

Comment: This is not only 99% wrong, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @user46945 Well, no one has ever referenced the gem on Heimdall's armour in the MCU. You are the first!