# Could the Bifrost Bridge be used to "extract" someone from a secure location?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

In the *Marvel's Agent's of S.H.I.E.L.D.* Season 2 episode "Who You Really Are", Sif comes to Earth on a mission:

> find and retreive a Kree. When she learns that Skye is an active Inhuman, she decides she should take her as well.

This raises an interesting question about the nature of the Bifrost Bridge between Midgard and Asgard. We know the Bridge has an effectively infinite range, and that it can even cross dimensions. We know that Heimdall can "see" people on Midgard, or elsewhere, and open the Bridge for them for the return trip.

However, in all of the cases we've seen in the MCU so far, two things have always been true:

1. The person using the Bridge has been a willing participant, or else accompanied by one (e.g. when Sif took Lorelei back in Season One)
2. The bridge opened a portal to the surface of another planet.

But, assuming Heimdall could find them, could he open the bridge, and forcibly extract a person back to Asgard without their consent? Would this work even if the person was hidden inside a building, or deep underground, without causing physical damage to the intervening walls or Earth's crust?

Since we've never seen this happen in the MCU, I'm particularly interested to know if something like this has been done in the graphic novels.

**Note:** Inspiration for this post came from the user [Sachin Shekhar](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/931/s-s), who asked a [similar question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83622/how-good-is-bifrost-bridge-in-comparison-with-star-trek-transporters).

Comment: The Avengers movie would have been different if Heimdall could just pluck Loki up from Midgard...

Comment: @HorusKol As I understand it, in the Avengers movie, the Bifrost was still broken and Odin had to send Thor to Earth himself.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield This is correct. [There's even a question about it](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/16156/5184).

Comment: Just to nitpick, the spoiler text is wrong. Sif's mission was to find the Kree and discover what he was up to. It had nothing to do with the character in question.

Comment: @Omegacron that's true, her fixation on the second character came later, the question works either way.

Comment: Not anymore! LOL

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can't speak really thoroughly to question #1 about the participant being unwilling, as I don't believe we've seen that occur in the MCU, but we can do some inferring.  Early in *Thor: The Dark World*, Thor & Friends bring some captives back to Asgard via Bifrost.  They went through without issue, which suggests that if you can escape from the Bifrost while being beamed, that there is a consequence to it that's worse than being imprisoned in Asgard's prisons.  Otherwise, we would see some escape attempts there.  We also see that active participation by the passenger isn't necessary, as they used the Bifrost to move the Aether in the prologue of *Thor: The Dark World*.

In the MCU we have seen the Bifrost not do #2.  At the start of *Thor: The Dark World*, the prologue introduces the backstory of the Aether.  At the end of the prologue, the Bifrost is used to hide the Aether, and it's deep underground on a world somewhere.  Admittedly, we didn't get to plainly see if this damaged the rock above, but it's clear the implication is that it can be used to teleport underground.

It's also important to understand the vastly different role and capabilities of the Bifrost between the comics and the MCU.  In the comics, Mjolnir is capable of creating portals between the realms on its own, the Bifrost doesn't serve the role it does in the films as a result.

Comment: huh. I had forgotten the Bifrost did that; if that's possible then presumably, at worst, they could send an Asgardian over to grab the target and drag them back.

Comment: as far as point #1, I'm mostly interested in whether the Bifrost "pulls" people across, or if they have to consciously "move" across it, but if that's not how things work in the comics then that question probably has no answer.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield I'd say that's addressed by them moving the Aether. It was just moving a big stone contraption, so the Bifrost must do all the moving.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say no.

On the latest Agents of Shield episode, when Sif was escorting another prisoner to Asgard; Coulson escorted Sif and the prisoner to a remote, outdoor location.

Keep in mind, they *have* a secured indoor facility and I see no reason to go to a remote open field if they could have just opened the bifrost directly to the holding cell.

She asked heimdall to open the bifrost, and he did, opening a portal through space to the field where Sif and the prisoner were standing, leaving a crop circle as it always does.

> A kree prisoner, to be specific

Comment: Maybe Coulson just didn't want that symbol burned into the floor of his holding cell?

Comment: I mean, he is the guy who carved a map into a wall

Comment: Maybe it requires more space than a cell allows for?

Comment: They have an hangar with the bus in it nearly as big as the clearing that was used which really points towards needing a line of sight.

Answer (score 5):

Based on what we see in *Thor Ragnarok*, it appears that either it can, or that at least Thor thinks it can.

> But, assuming Heimdall could find them, could he open the bridge, and forcibly extract a person back to Asgard without their consent?

We effectively see this. Skurge opens the Bifrost to transport Thor, but inadvertently also transports just the head of the dragon that was chasing him. Skurge did not mean to transport the dragon, and the dragon clearly did not have any intention to go to Asgard.

However, we see that it is possible to escape the Bifrost beam, as both Thor and Loki are knocked out of the Bifrost's beam mid-voyage.

This means that the Bifrost pulls its passengers regardless of consent, but that it is not necessarily a guaranteed transport of the passenger.

> Would this work even if the person was hidden inside a building, or deep underground, without causing physical damage to the intervening walls or Earth's crust?

While we don't actually see this occur, Thor was underground when he initially tries calling for Heimdall to open the Bifrost with the full expectation that he would be rescued from beneath the surface of the planet.

Comment: We also see this when Heimdall transports a part of a car when he brings Thor and Jane to Asgard during `Thor: Dark World`