# Who bought the Avengers Tower?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, spider-man-homecoming

In *Spider-Man: Homecoming*,

> we learn that Tony Stark has sold the Avengers Tower in Manhattan in order to buy the new Avengers facility in upstate New York.

**So who bought the Avengers Tower and what do they plan to do with the building?**

Comment: I'm hoping Marvel Studios is being Sneaky and sharing the rights with Fox on the Fantastic Four. I can totally see it being the Baxter Building.

Comment: As one very misguided answer attempt stated it really sounds almost like a baxter building deal. Aside from that I'm wondering though why he had to sell it in order to buy the new one (money shouldnt be HIS problem should it?).

Comment: @Thomas: “why he had to sell it in order to buy the new one” — I suspect he didn’t. The new Avengers facility has been up-and-running since Avengers 2; while it’s possible that Avengers Tower was sold [two–eight years previously](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163185/which-year-does-spider-man-homecoming-take-place-in) and Stark Enterprises are only moving out now, I’d bet the tower sale happened independently of the new facility being built.

Comment: I honestly do not know, but the Avengers tower was initially the Stark tower correct? Perhaps it was actually an asset of his company the entire time? Maybe Pepper forced the sale with the newer facility already built?... he or she saw no reason to keep it? Or just like Stark helping out Spiderman he wanted to help the Fantastic Four get on their feet... assuming it will be the Baxter building...

Comment: Another possibility I've read is that it could have been an Oscorp purchase.

Comment: @JAB where did you read that? Link?

Comment: @CodeMed Some examples are http://comicbook.com/marvel/2017/07/10/avengers-tower-oscorp-daily-bugle-bought-sold-/ and http://heavy.com/movies/2017/07/spider-man-homecoming-who-purchased-bought-the-avengers-tower-oscorp-theories/

Comment: @JAB So why not document the theories in an answer with your links to give credibility?

Comment: Humorous answer: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/931/sachin-stark

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no explicit evidence as to who bought it. My money is on some megacorporation just needing a new location, but another good theory comes from Screenrant:

> One of the leading theories about the Avengers Tower's new owner is that it was purchased by the MCU's Reed Richards for the Fantastic Four. If so, the building could be rebranded as the Baxter Building in Phase 5. In Marvel Comics, the Baxter Building is the 35-story headquarters of Marvel's First Family.

I think that would work? I hope so, really.

[Source](https://screenrant.com/avengers-stark-tower-purchase-bought-identity-theories/)

Comment: Imagine when they find a couple suits in the basement