# Did the UN Council have to approve Iron Man's actions in Spider-Man: Homecoming?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war, spider-man-homecoming

As of *Captain America: Civil War*, the remaining Avengers are under the purview of a UN Council established by the Sokovia Accords.  The implication during the discussion about the Accords is that this council would decide when and where the Avengers would be deployed, and also when they would **not** be deployed.

In the chronologically next installment of the Marvel Cinematic Universe<sup>*</sup>, *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, we see Iron Man taking action several times, including

> repairing the ship that Spider-Man failed to repair on his own

Are we meant to understand that, due to the Sokovia Accords, the UN Council had to approve Iron Man to take that action?  Does their involvement only come into play for situations that require the entire team of Avengers, rather than a single individual member?  It seems unlikely that a UN Council could convene and reach a decision in time for Iron Man to carry out such a time-critical mission, given how suddenly the situation presented itself.

<sup>*(Barring any timeline weirdness such as discussed in [Which year does Spider-Man: Homecoming take place in?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163185/which-year-does-spider-man-homecoming-take-place-in))</sup>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In a nutshell, the Sokovia accords restricted both organizational and individual rights to operate in any country without either the pre-authorization of the UN **or** the authorization of the country in which the operation will take place.

Tony Stark was probably within operating parameters, as he was acting in joint with the FBI (Which is both government authorization, and under justifiable parameters for bustin' out the Iron-man suit).

Outside of the action side of things, as long as Iron man doesn't engage in any conflicts or cross international borders, Stark is O.K. with moving around in his Suit.

http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Sokovia_Accords#cite_note-CACW-0