# What are the exact years of the MCU movies?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

The events in the first *Avengers* film transpired in 2012 (as shown in *Endgame),* and Tony Stark referencing them in *Infinity War* reveals that these events happened six years ago, which means *Infinity War* was set in 2018.

However, the events in *Thor: Ragnarok* happened at the same time as the events in *Civil War,* which was set in 2016. And *Infinity War* takes place right after the events in *Thor: Ragnarok*, as shown in the post-credits scene of the latter.

Please clarify, although Bruce stated in *Ragnarok* that he has been Hulk for 2 years (which would have been 2017 since *Age of Ultron* was set in 2015).

Did the post-credits scene in *Ragnarok* happen a year later, after Asgard was destroyed by Surtur?

Comment: I just thought maybe I missed something so I asked. But thanks anyway.

Comment: "However, the events in Thor Ragnarok happened the same time as the events in Civil War which was set in 2016." What makes you think this? As you mention in your question, it's established in Ragnarok that the events of that movie are taking place two years after Age of Ultron.

Comment: I just rewatched the ending of Ragnarok, and some non-zero amount of time definitely passes between the final scene of the movie (≈2017) and the post-credits scene. Thor is wearing very different armor between the two scenes. Additionally, there's discussion earlier in the movie about the lengths of time needed to travel between various planets (like Sakaar and Asgard). It seems reasonable Thanos would meet up with the Asgardians somewhere along that journey; maybe several months later.

Comment: [Welcome to the rabbit hole, friend](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163185/which-year-does-spider-man-homecoming-take-place-in).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Marvel Studios published an official timeline for the MCU in the book *Marvel Studios: The First 10 Years*. According to [ScreenRant](https://screenrant.com/mcu-timeline-official/), this timeline places both *Infinity War* and *Thor: Ragnarok* in 2017.

[image]

To clarify those movies' positioning in regards to the other movies you mentioned, this means *Ragnarok* takes place two years after *Age of Ultron* (which takes place in 2015), and one year after *Civil War* (in 2016).

Comment: So Infinity War happened in 2017 then? Not 2018?

Comment: I found a flip-through here; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QSm0QrpO0uA

Comment: As long as we ignore [the on-screen caption in *Spider-Man:Homecoming*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163185/which-year-does-spider-man-homecoming-take-place-in) (which I think we should), this totally works!

Answer (score 1):

The official chronology of MCU events is given in the book [Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline](https://books.google.com/books/about/Marvel_Studios_the_Marvel_Cinematic_Univ.html?id=aeqSzwEACAAJ). According to this book, the timeline is as follows:

###### *Avengers: Age of Ultron* — Spring 2015

###### *Captain America: Civil War* — Spring 2016

###### *Thor: Ragnarok* — Fall 2017

[image: relevant part of the Official Timeline]

###### Post-credits scene of *Ragnarok* and start of *Avengers: Infinity War* — Spring 2018

[image: relevant part of the Official Timeline]

So, the post-credits scene of *Ragnarok* did not happen right after Asgard was destroyed by Surtur, but a few months later, when Thanos attacked the Asgardian ship.