# Are specific dates of the Snap and the Blip known? Why or why not?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

The Marvel Cinematic Universe fandom page gives the dates of [the Snap](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Snap) and [the Blip](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Blip) as "Spring 2018" and "October 2023".

You would think that these dates would be well known to all in-universe similar to, but way beyond, D-Day, Pearl Habor, Armistice Day, 9/11, etc. (pick your date depending on your culture)...

**Are there any more specific dates known for these events?** At what level of canon?

Bonus Question: If there is no specific date known, was this a specific behind-the-scenes decision to avoid issues in the real world each year?

Comment: Comment:   For example, from video in *Far From Home*, it seems we can infer that the Blip almost certianly occured on a weekday.

Comment: I'd be highly surprised if there's any specific dates to these events. The MCU has very few dates and very few specific dates in it at all.

Comment: And even [the relative dates contradict each other](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163185/which-year-does-spider-man-homecoming-take-place-in)

Comment: It's one thing for the characters to know it and another thing for them to say it where it becomes canon.  It would be like saying, "Christmas, December 25."  This allows the writers to leave it up in the air in case a given date proves to be unworkable.

Comment: I'm going to add to my previous comment that we can probably infer that the Blip occurred on one of the twenty following days: Oct 2-6, 9-13,16-20 or 23-27.   It is a weekday in October 2023 and there's no sign of Halloween, so 10/30 and 10/31 are out.  Arguably 10/26 and 10/27 are unlikely.

Comment: Are you limiting to just Earth dates, or Asgardian, Kree, Skrull, Flerken, Sakaaran, Sovereign, or Celestial dating systems fair game?

Comment: The wiki that you linked puts the dates at May 31st, 2018 and October 17th, 2023. But I'm sure they are just "best guesses".

Comment: The comic in which thanos snapped his fingers premiered on may 21, 1991 so maybe its the same in the movie

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure of the validity in this but I remember hearing somewhere that it ended on October 18th, 2023. Not completely sure tho

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What is the source for that date?  What level of canonicity is it?